# Activeadmin render 'new' gives Couldn't find User without an id when trying to override the create controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm trying to create a page in activeadmin where a user can go in and create new user accounts.

I'm overriding the default create method for my User model with the code below.

I'm getting the error `Couldn't find User without an ID` when I try to render the `new` page.

Why would I be getting this error when trying to re-render the `new` action?

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  permit_params do
    permitted = [:email, :encrypted_password]
    permitted << :admin if current_user.is_admin?
    permitted
  end

  # We're overriding the new and edit controller methods to properly create users with devise. Otherwise the passwords don't get encrypted
  controller do

      def create
        user = User.new
        user.name = params[:user][:name]
        user.email = params[:user][:email]
        user.admin = params[:user][:admin]
        user.password = params[:user][:encrypted_password]
        user.password_confirmation = params[:user][:encrypted_password]

        if user.save
          redirect_to admin_user_path(user)
        else
          flash.now[:error] = user.errors.full_messages
          render 'new'     # THIS CAUSES THE ERROR "Couldn't find User without an ID"
          #redirect_to new_admin_user_path # This redirect works just fine
        end
      end

    end

end
```

Logs:

```
Started GET "/admin/users/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-09 21:34:35 -0500
Processing by Admin::UsersController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@myapp/bundler/gems/active_admin-739b93bf9d22/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb (31.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 37ms (Views: 34.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


Started GET "/admin/users/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-09 21:34:42 -0500
Processing by Admin::UsersController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@myapp/bundler/gems/active_admin-739b93bf9d22/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb (32.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 60ms (Views: 35.4ms | ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)


Started POST "/admin/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-09 21:34:44 -0500
Processing by Admin::UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Aa6TBt0LADDcKAHs+gFokQroSVgTnxtlgLwzvCovIcs=", "user"=>{"name"=>"", "email"=>"", "encrypted_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "admin"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@myapp/bundler/gems/active_admin-739b93bf9d22/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb (14.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find User without an ID:
```

Comment: You do realize you're completely bypassing strong parameters to set unsanitized user input on a user model, right? i.e. your `permit_params` isn't actually being used here. instead of `params[:user][:name]` you should be using `permitted_params[:name]`. Also, are you *sure* passwords aren't getting encrypted when using the built-in create method? I've never seen an issue like that before.

Comment: So i eventually ended up getting this figured out without having to override the controller method, BUT this is still a valid question. As far as permitted params, I don't know how using permitted_params is any different. I understand the concept of actually specifying which params are permitted, but I don't know how that is different. I'm not saying you're wrong, but i'm not familiar with the method permitted_params. Can you point me to some documentation?

Comment: `permitted_params` is actually the method that `permit_params` generates. `permit_params` is just a nicer DSL. `permitted_params` is what InheritedResources uses by default for all create/update actions, thus what ActiveAdmin uses. It's not really well documented, but that's how it works. If you were to use `permitted_params` instead of `params[:user]`, it will keep the unpermitted params from being set when you don't want to, i.e. only an admin should be able to set `params[:user][:admin]` successfully.

Comment: did you get  any solution of your problem ?

Comment: About the permitted_params, you could use them like this: 
`user_params = permitted_params[:user]` and `user = User.new(user_params)`

Answer (score 8):

I'm a little late to the game here but just ran into this. Use `@user` instead of `user`.

Answer (score 5):

If someone is still looking at this then adysson's answer was quite helpful for me.

```
if user.save
  # DO YOUR JOB
  redirect_to admin_user_path(user)
else
  @resource = user
  render :new
end
```

Doing this will show resource errors under the input fields instead of flash message.

Comment: using \@user as suggested above did not work for me, using \@resource seems to be key to getting it working (activeadmin (2.9.0)

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem aswell and have not found a solution yet. If somebody found something I would be pleased to hear about it.

As @Catfish already showed in his code as a current workaround I'm using redirect_to

```
redirect_to new_admin_[resource]_path
```

instead of

```
render :new
```

Sadly this way all input by the user is lost so

```
render :new
```

would be the preferred solution

Answer (score 3):

I encoutered same issue, my solution is something like:

```
if user.save
  # DO YOUR JOB
else
  flash.now[:error] = user.errors.full_messages
  @resource = User.new(permitted_params)
  render template: 'active_admin/resource/new'
end
```

Just adjust initialization of @resource with your needs. This solution works for me with ActiveAdmin in state of the commit ref '1713ec9cb43a', don't know how it works with current/last version.